# Use DataFrame Column Name as R Function Argument

Tags: r, function, dataframe, arguments

```
fun <- function(dataframe, var){
    print(data$var)
}

dataset <- data.frame(a = 1:6, b = 12:17, c = 3:8)

fun(dataset, a)
```

Essentially, I would like to do something like this where I can just pass one of the column names into a function and be able to use it to call that column later on.

I know the group_by function handles it somehow, but when I went into debugging mode and tried to figure it out, I couldn't make heads or tails of what was actually doing what I wanted.

Comment: Pass in a quoted string `"a"` and in function use brackets: `data[[var]]`

Comment: fun <- function(dataframe, var){  print(dataframe[c(var)])}

Comment: There is another issue here: The function parameter is named `dataframe` but in the body `data` is referenced.

Answer (score -1):

To do this `dplyr`-like, you need to use tidyevaluation. First, you need to `enquo()` `var`, and then refer to `var` with `!!` :

```
library(dplyr)

fun <- function(dataframe, var){
  var <- enquo(var)
  select(dataframe, !!var)
}

dataset <- data.frame(a = 1:6, b = 12:17, c = 3:8)

fun(dataset, a)
```

You can find a good `tidyeval` tuto [here](http://colinfay.me/tidyeval-1/).

Best,

Colin